# YouCompleteMe and Syntastic compatibility?

Tags: vim

What I want to do is to have YouCompleteMe do completions and Syntastic to check for errors but it looks that doesn't go together.

When YouCompleteMe is disabled then Synatstic works, and vice versa.
but when both are enabled, completion does not work and syntastic does not show any errors.

What configuration do I need to make this work?

here are my options: (note scroll down to see all the options)

```
"
" YouCompleteMe options
"

let g:ycm_register_as_syntastic_checker = 1

"YCM will put icons in Vim's gutter on lines that have a diagnostic set.
"Turning this off will also turn off the YcmErrorLine and YcmWarningLine
"highlighting
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_signs = 1
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_highlighting = 0
let g:ycm_always_populate_location_list = 1 "default 0
let g:ycm_open_loclist_on_ycm_diags = 1 "default 1


let g:ycm_complete_in_strings = 1 "default 1
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 1 "default 0
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = '' "default ''


let g:ycm_server_use_vim_stdout = 0 "default 0 (logging to console)
let g:ycm_server_log_level = 'info' "default info


let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '' "where to search for .ycm_extra_conf.py if not found
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 1


let g:ycm_goto_buffer_command = 'same-buffer' "[ 'same-buffer', 'horizontal-split', 'vertical-split', 'new-tab' ]
let g:ycm_filetype_whitelist = { '*': 1 }
let g:ycm_key_invoke_completion = '<C-Space>'








"
" syntastic settings
"

let g:syntastic_enable_signs = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1


let g:syntastic_cpp_checkers = ['gcc']

let g:syntastic_auto_jump = 1
let g:syntastic_enable_balloons = 1

let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler = 'g++'
let g:syntastic_cpp_compiler_options = '-std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra'



let g:syntastic_cpp_check_header = 1
let g:syntastic_cpp_auto_refresh_includes = 1

"let b:syntastic_cpp_cflags = '-I/home/user/dev/cpp/boost_1_55_0'
let g:syntastic_cpp_include_dirs = [ 
            \ '/opt/boost_1_55_0',
            \ '/opt/cryptopp-5.6.2',
            \ '/opt/llvm_install/include/llvm',
            \ '/opt/llvm_install/include/clang' ]
```

Comment: Read `:h youcompleteme-why-did-ycm-stop-using-syntastic-for-diagnostics-display`. Basically YCM does all of the functionality of `syntastic` so there should be no reason to use syntactic. I believe YCM also tries to disable syntastic, although I might be wrong about this which may explain why things are acting weird.

Comment: Thanks, you actually solved my problem by directing me where to look for problem. I find out few useful YouCompleteMe variables which make syntastic not needed plug-in at all. more info can be fond on git website.

Comment: I recommend posting your findings as an answer so that other people who have the same question can see what solved your problem.

Comment: Yes tnx, I added all the information I have.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is my modified version of .vimrc (only YCM settings) file so that now with these settings YouCompleteMe works with all the features + I do not need any of syntastic features any more since it's not needed, except only 2, and that's auto opening of location list and auto jumping to the errors.

```
"
" YouCompleteMe options
"

let g:ycm_register_as_syntastic_checker = 1 "default 1
let g:Show_diagnostics_ui = 1 "default 1

"will put icons in Vim's gutter on lines that have a diagnostic set.
"Turning this off will also turn off the YcmErrorLine and YcmWarningLine
"highlighting
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_signs = 1
let g:ycm_enable_diagnostic_highlighting = 0
let g:ycm_always_populate_location_list = 1 "default 0
let g:ycm_open_loclist_on_ycm_diags = 1 "default 1


let g:ycm_complete_in_strings = 1 "default 1
let g:ycm_collect_identifiers_from_tags_files = 0 "default 0
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = '' "default ''


let g:ycm_server_use_vim_stdout = 0 "default 0 (logging to console)
let g:ycm_server_log_level = 'info' "default info


let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.ycm_extra_conf.py'  "where to search for .ycm_extra_conf.py if not found
let g:ycm_confirm_extra_conf = 1


let g:ycm_goto_buffer_command = 'same-buffer' "[ 'same-buffer', 'horizontal-split', 'vertical-split', 'new-tab' ]
let g:ycm_filetype_whitelist = { '*': 1 }
let g:ycm_key_invoke_completion = '<C-Space>'


nnoremap <F11> :YcmForceCompileAndDiagnostics <CR>
```

I may also add that in order to make YCM work with full support, I built following from source:

Vim from source + all the latest patches applied into the source before the build.
llvm + clang libraries (latest stable) built from source.
YCM built with support againt fresh clang libs.

Also it's important to setup your .ycm_extra_conf.py file. (flags and includes mainly)
here are mines: (scrol down if you want to see them all)

```
flags = [
'-Wall',
'-Wextra',
'-std=c++11',
'c++',

#Standard includes
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/c++/4.7',



#GTK includes
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/gtk-3.0',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/glib-2.0',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib',
'-isystem',
'/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/pango-1.0',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/cairo',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0',
'-isystem',
'/usr/include/atk-1.0',
'-isystem',
'-I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0',
'-isystem',
'-I/usr/include/freetype2',
'-isystem',
'-I/usr/include/pixman-1',
'-isystem',
'-I/usr/include/libpng12',

#current dir
'-I',
'.',

#custom libraries
'-I',
'/opt/boost_1_55_0',
'-I',
'/opt/cryptopp-5.6.2',
'-I',
'/opt/llvm_install/include'
]
```

If you do GTK+ coding then this list may be of help to you.
btw, if you wonder what does -isystem mean right before include dir, it means that YouCompleteMe (clang/clang++ compiler) will now show warnings and errors from these headers. (which are false positive 99% of the time)

btw, Sinastic checking is done with clang compiler (background compiling) while building it self can be done with any compiler kind, of course.

Thanks!