# VIM syntax error highlight with youcompleteme

Tags: python, vim, syntastic, youcompleteme

I recently started using `Youcompleteme` vim plugin, and it is just perfect for me. The only thing I'm missing now from VIM is a syntax error highlight. I was using `Syntastic`, but as I read in other threads and on the `YCM` github page it is not compatible with `YCM` as all of its functions can be accessed from `YCM`.

However I can't really find any syntax highlighting within `YCM`, and I cant get `Syntastic` working together with `YCM`.

Is there a syntax error highlighting for python in `YCM`? If not is there any alternative plugins to `Syntastic` that works with `YCM`?

Comment: I couldn't understand why `YCM` and `Syntastic` are not compatible. Could you share the thread?

Comment: You can read about it in the github page https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/, and in this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500281/youcompleteme-and-syntastic-compatibility. Actually YMC disables Syntastic if you have both installed.

Comment: A quote from the linked SO page: "Basically YCM does all of the functionality of syntastic so there should be no reason to use syntactic. I believe YCM also tries to disable syntastic, although I might be wrong about this which may explain why things are acting weird"

Comment: @GáborErdős You're referring to a two years old thread, and you're reading it the wrong way.  What problems do __you__ have when trying to  use syntastic together with YCM __today__?

Comment: Syntastic does not work. What i use `:help syntastic` i got a message from YMC help with the very same message you can find at the UP TO DATE github page i just linked

Comment: @GáborErdős "Does not work" provides zero useful information.  If you want to solve this you might consider posting an issue at the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues), explaining in detail what you did, what did you expect to happen, and what happened instead.  Minimal test files illustrating the problem might be useful too.

Comment: Syntastic overlaps with YCM only for C / C++ and Objective-C / Objective-C++, and then you can resolve the conflict by setting `g:ycm_show_diagnostics_ui`.  See `:h syntastic-ycm` for details.  They are supposed to work fine together for Python.  If they don't then you should file a bug report.